# Cannot find how to add settings to firestore 9.0.0 React Native

Tags: firebase

I want to add this,
`firebase.firestore().settings({ experimentalForceLongPolling: true });` 
to my React Native App and I can't find how to do that in firestore 9.0.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`import {initializeFirestore} from 'firebase/firestore';`

Got to do this before you initialize a instance.
`initializeFirestore(settings);`